# Rails: Does this belong in the model or controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a method which runs several rake commands.

Does this method belong in the controller or in the model?

My intention is to run this method upon every Save or Update

Comment: could you paste some of your code? based on `My intention is to run this method upon every Save or Update` it should be implemented in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This belongs in the models, write an `Observer` that will observe the appropriate model, and put this action there...

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

Answer (score 0):

Save and Update are model operations, so I'd put it there.

Comment: You'd put it in the model and call the method from the controller?

Comment: If it's to be called on every save and update, follow fd's advice and use filters to have them called automatically by the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a before_save or after_save filter in the model to call arbitrary code, which could include a rake task I guess (I wouldn't do anything too heavyweight though since it could harm the responsiveness of your application).